# Oracle DB RMAN backup

Tags: database, oracle, rman

Iam having a weekly full backup in my database what i need is a script that first verify the new backup if it is valid then delete the old one
iam doing this for saving space on my filesystem
the Oracle database version = 12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append this checking at initial RMAN script

```
rman> crosscheck backup;
rman> crosscheck copy;
rman> delete noprompt expired backupset;
# Compress backup to reduce space (lab/test is ok, prod have to pay for license)
CONFIGURE COMPRESSION ALGORITHM 'HIGH' AS OF RELEASE 'DEFAULT' OPTIMIZE FOR LOAD FALSE;
...
# database backup takes place here!
...
```

Append this deletion at the end of current RMAN Script

```
rman> configure retention policy to redundancy 1;
rman> crosscheck backup;
rman> crosscheck copy;
rman> delete noprompt obsolete;
```