# How to write a script of getting backup of remote Oracle database

Tags: database-administration, oracle19c

I have an Oracle database 19c with IP, *x.x.x.a* that have a lot of important tables. I want to get backup of that and save it on another system with IP,*x.x.x.b*. I did this actions on the *x.x.x.b* system:

- Install an Oracle database 19c which won't be used to have data in his own.
- Install Oracle database client 19c and set ORACLE_HOME in **~/.bashrc**
- Set JAVA_HOME
- Finally, use this script to get backup of the Oracle Database on *x.x.x.a*:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/oracle_database_client
  export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
  rman target sys/******@//x.x.x.a:1521/ORCL

  BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG FORMAT '/home/oracle/backup_oracle_process/backup_files/%U';
  exit;
  ```

I prefer to get backup using script in the clear way and use the script in crontab to run every week. I gave +x permission to the script,*backup_script.sh*, and run it. But unfortunately, it stop on **RMAN>** prompt and when exited from that this error message was shown:

> BACKUP command not found.

Moreover, I read all questions about this subject like this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72397334/6640504

But none of them does what I want.

Would you please guide me how to solve the problem and have a script to get backup of Oracle database?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just starting RMAN and not passing it any commands. Then when you exit RMAN you are trying to run the RMAN commands from the command prompt (rather than in RMAN).

Put your RMAN backup command(s) into a file:

```
BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG FORMAT '/home/oracle/backup_oracle_process/backup_files/%U';
```

Then your script should use `@filename` to pass the name of a command file to execute (see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/starting-interacting-with-rman-client.html#GUID-5FF51A4E-BC27-41A9-AA83-FF6E761C2535)):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/oracle_database_client
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
rman target sys/******@//x.x.x.a:1521/ORCL @your_rman_backup_script_file_name
```

Where `@your_rman_backup_script_file_name` is the name of the file you just created containing the backup command.

Comment: @MTO, thank you for your answer but I received this error: ```using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
allocated channel: ORA_DISK_1
channel ORA_DISK_1: SID=160 device type=DISK
specification does not match any archived log in the repository
backup cancelled because there are no files to backup
Finished backup at 19-FEB-24
Starting backup at 19-FEB-24
using channel ORA_DISK_1
RMAN-03002: failure of backup plus archivelog command at 02/19/2024 19:56:59
RMAN-06149: cannot BACKUP DATABASE in NOARCHIVELOG mode```

Comment: @MTO, I tried to change the database status from *noarchivelog* to *archivelog*; but it give me the error about *recovery database*.

Comment: @M_Gh This is the wrong place to ask database administration questions - you should be asking at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - I was answering the "why doesn't the script run?" question, is vaguely on topic as its writing the script - but getting the correct syntax for backups is a DBA question and is definitely off-topic.

Comment: @MTO, would you please take a look at this question https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/336042/285283 ? Many thanks.